# Microsoft Media Foundation SDK samples download

Tags: sdk, media, sample, ms-media-foundation

I'm sorry to ask such a question but right now it's two hours since I'm trying to find Microsoft Media Foundation SDK samples [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371827(v=vs.85).aspx). I've installed latest Microsoft SDK 8.1 and Microsoft SDK 10 and there are no MF SDK samples. And link from MSDN (for example link from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756740(v=vs.85).aspx)) does not work anymore.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will find these samples in Windows SDK 7.1: [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442), in \Samples\multimedia\mediafoundation.

Also, samples can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation) in Microsoft's Windows-classic-samples repository, under Win7Samples.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that these samples cannot be acquired via any later SDK?

Comment: @BenVoigt: To my best knowledge they took samples away from SDK 8.0 and put *some of them* [online](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Windows-8-Desktop-Samples/view/SamplePack#content). Then newer samples went also to GitHub. MSDN somewhere still lists old sample locations relative to SDK root, as it was with SDK 7.1 and earlier, but a lot of the samples are no longer included into the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for MediaFoundation samples using the Windows 10 Universal App Platform, a bunch of them were just released yesterday as part of the [Universal Samples repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples).

In particular, these samples all use MediaFoundation:

- [AdaptiveStreaming](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming)
- [AdvancedCasting](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AdvancedCasting)
- [AudioCategory](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCategory)
- [AudioCreation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation)
- [BackgroundAudio](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio)
- [BasicMediaCasting](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicMediaCasting)
- [LiveDash](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/LiveDash)
- [MIDI](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MIDI)
- [MediaEditing](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaEditing)
- [MediaTranscoding](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaTranscoding)
- [SimpleCommunication](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleCommunication)
- [SystemMediaTransportControls](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SystemMediaTransportControls)
- [VideoPlayback](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VideoPlayback)
- [WindowsAudioSession](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WindowsAudioSession)